# Can someone provide a "hello world" example of JSX being used with out React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xml, babeljs, jsx

I keep hearing that the two are not tied together, that you can compile JSX to JavaScript with out React but I have never seen it.

For example:

```
function Welcome() {
  return <h1>Hello, World</h1>;
}
```

If I feed this to babel compiler I get:

```
function Welcome() {
  return /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("h1", null, "Hello, World");
}
```

which requires the React library.

You can see this online here:

https://babeljs.io/repl/

Can someone provide a Hello World example of JSX being used without React?

Comment: If you don't want to use React (eg, not using props, states, effects etc.) then why not use `innerHTML`? Previously `innerHTML` was cumbersome but it's a lot less cumbersome now with template literals. You can almost make it look like React code

Answer (score 2):

[Here's a good resource.](https://blog.r0b.io/post/using-jsx-without-react/) All you need is to write a `createElement` function, to replace `React.createElement` with.

```js
// Setup some data
const name = 'Geoff'
const friends = ['Sarah', 'James', 'Hercule']

// Create some dom elements
const app = (
  <div className="app">
    <h1 className="title"> Hello, world! </h1>
    <p> Welcome back, {name} </p>
    <p>
      <strong>Your friends are:</strong>
    </p>
    <ul>
      {friends.map(name => (
        <li>{name}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  </div>
)

// Render our dom elements
window.document.getElementById('app').replaceWith(app)
```

```html
<div id='app'></div>
<script>
window.React = {
// A jsx pragma method to create html dom elements (more info below)
  createElement(tagName, attrs = {}, ...children) {
    const elem = Object.assign(document.createElement(tagName), attrs)
    for (const child of children) {
      if (Array.isArray(child)) elem.append(...child)
      else elem.append(child)
    }
    return elem
  }
};
</script>
```

The above is using the client-side Babel transpiler, which automatically transforms JSX syntax into references to `React.createElement` - but instead of importing the React library, a custom `window.React` is defined, with your custom `createElement` function.

For pre-compiled projects, you need to set your Babel config to

```
{
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx", { "pragma": "createElement" }]
  ],
  "comments": false
}
```

with a global `createElement` function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't want to write my own library to convert JSX to JavaScript.  I assume someone has already done this.  Something like React but much much simpler as I don't need a virtual DOM and many of the features React provides.  Surely someone has done this, where the wheel doe not need re-invention.

Comment: You do not need to write your own library - you said all you wanted was to be able to use JSX without React, right? That's what the code in the answer does - all you need is that (example) 8-line `createElement` function.